# Which ways should be performed detecting outliers before k-means clustering?

Tags: clustering, outliers, k-means

I will make k-means clustering for a segmentation project.But I know that this algorithm is effectable from outliers.Which way should I perform for detecting outliers before doing k-means algorithm? For example should I perform anomaly detection algorithm on the data set to detect outliers and after detecting and excluding outliers ,performing k-means algorithm for more stable clustering? Or Should I detect outliers by using k-means algorithm itself by finding average distances and finding the outliers beyond these distances? What approach should be taken for detecting outliers and making more stable clustering? I need your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try any of the standard outlier methods, such as kNN, LOF, LOOP, INFLO, etc.

There are also robust k-means variations such as k-means--.

Answer (score 0):

Detect outlier first,  if you data set maybe contain outlier.

Try the isolationForest method, it's fast and efficient to detect the outliers.

**update:**

isolationForest

papers:https://cs.nju.edu.cn/zhouzh/zhouzh.files/publication/tkdd11.pdf

python code:http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.IsolationForest.html

Comment: I'd be interested to hear more.

Comment: which algorithm or method should be used for detecting outliers ? Thanks

Comment: Not my downvote, but the link to the papers is dead.

Comment: I can visit it. Maybe you should use proxy to visit Chinese websites.

Comment: Link to the PDF is alive and accessible (EU, Greece)